# Why is my enter selection not empty after data updates?

Tags: d3.js

I use d3 as part of a react project. At some point I display data (array of javascript objects) as shown below.

When I update the 2D data array I would like to update the position+size of the updated object(s) and conditionally draw the border.

However, I noticed that instead of only updating the svg objects related to the updated data, d3 **always** updates the first element of my data array and performs the enter operations for all other elements. Eventhough the objects haven't changed. The array reference should also be the same.

Why is that?

```
let bound = d3
  .select(this.svgRef.current)
  .selectAll(".square")
  .data(this.props.data, d => d);

//enter
bound
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "square")
  .attr("id", d => d.id)
  .attr("x", d => {console.log("enter", d); return d.x})
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("width", d => d.width)
  .attr("height", d => d.height)
  .style("fill", d => {
    return d.c;
  })
  .style("stroke", d => {
    if (d.id == this.props.focus) {
      return "#FF0000";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });

//updates
bound
  .attr("x", d => { return d.x })
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("width", d => d.width)
  .attr("height", d => d.height)
  .style("fill", d => {
    return d.c;
  })
  .style("stroke", d => {
    if (d.id == this.props.focus) {
      return "#FF0000";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });


bound.exit().remove();
```

The data has the following format:

```
[{
  "id":"1.png","c":"#FFFFFF",
  "d":["No Data"],
  "index":0,
  "x":0,
  "y":0,
  "width":115,
  "height":16
}, { 
  "id":"2.png",
  "c":"#FFFFFF",
  "d":["Example Data"],
  "index":1,
  "x":115,
  "y":0,
  "width":115,
  "height":16
}, ...]
```

Comment: `.data(this.props.data, d => d.id)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem seems to be an incorrect key function. The identity function doesn't seem to work with arrays of objects.